# How to Alternate x labels in seaborn?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm trying to plot a countplot with seaborn with the following code:

```
sns.set(rc={'figure.figsize':(15,10)})
ax = sns.countplot(hue="PRODUCTS", x="CATEGORIES",data=df)
plt.show()
```

But the categorical labels would overlap each other. Like this:

[image]

I could succesfully rotate the xticks but I would like to **alternate** them like in the following image:

[image]

In the previous image this method was used:

```
ax = sns.barplot(data=to_plot, x='Channel', y='% of leads assigned')
tweak_x_ticks(ax, alternate=True)
```

but `tweak_x_ticks` it's not a seaborn or matplotlib built-in method. How can I alternate the x labels? In other words, how can you define `tweak_x_ticks`?

Comment: Where do you have the code that uses `tweak_x_ticks` from? Does that not define it?

Comment: The example that I have doesn't contain the declaration of that method. I suspect that is an import of a custom library. I added to the problem explanation because the method's name could give a hint of the implementation of the answer in matplotlib

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible implementation of `tweak_x_ticks` could be (untested):

```
def tweak_x_ticks(ax, alternate=True):
    if not alternate:
        return
    ax.figure.canvas.draw()
    ax.set_xticklabels(["\n"*(i%2) + label.get_text() for i, label in enumerate(ax.get_xticklabels())])
```